# AWS Code Pipeline Metrics

Tags: aws-codepipeline

For a pipeline that is setup with multiple stages and each stage with one or more actions, is there a way to obtain metrics like time taken for each stage and each action to get completed.

For example, if there is a dev build stage with one build action, is there a way to get the time taken for this stage to get completed in a pipeline run or execution.

I think of a workaround by adding an "Ïnvoke" action before and after the actual action/stage where a custom lambda target can keep track of each stage activity.

Is there a way to achieve this in an easier way??